# Adding a component with mat-expansion-panel to mat-accordian

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a component with a `mat-expansion-component` and I want to place this component in a `mat-accordian`. This works except for the Styling.

```html
<mat-accordion>
    <app-panel1></app-panel1>
    <app-panel2></app-panel2>
</mat-accordion>
```

`app-panel.html` panel1 & panel2 have same format.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            Title
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
            Description
        </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
        Content
    </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

What's happening:

[image: What's happening]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

[taken from the angular material docs](https://v14.material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from:

```
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.mat-accordion .mat-expansion-panel:first-of-type {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

And since it's displayed like this, it's applying for the start and the end

```
<app-panel1>
    <mat-expansion-panel></mat-expansion-panel>
</app-panel1>
```

So you can override in your component, this attribute to not be applied. For example in `app-panel1.component.scss`

```
:host{
  .mat-expansion-panel:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Its actually `:host` not `::host`.